# Android - Crops Image while Converting to PDF

Tags: android, image, pdf, image-processing, itext

Its a bit weird situation i am using `com.itextpdf:itextg` to convert image to pdf and it is cropping the image and taking only 25% of it. It works fine in one of the phone but crops indefinitely in other phones mostly samsung series

below is my code

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));
document.open();
ImageView iv = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageViewNamed);
iv.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap img = iv.getDrawingCache(true);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
document.add(myImg);
stream.close();
document.close();
```

Comment: This behaviour could be caused by different implementations of the drawing cache in views by manufacturers. Maybe some Samsung devices have less cache to store the image and this result in a cropped image inside the PDF. I suggest you to not trust the drawingCache, instead create your own custom implementation to convert images to PDF

Comment: hey thanks @MatPag how could we tackle this situation then? and if i save the same drawing cache to jpg or png then the image is fine. problem is with pdf only

Comment: what's the source of your image? Why are you getting it from the imageview?

Comment: because we crop and edit the image a bit before saving it or putting it in pdf

Comment: Are you using a library to crop and edit the image?

Comment: yes `com.github.IsseiAoki:SimpleCropView` but thats not the problem @MatPag after croping and editing i save 2 files from same stream 1 is pdf and second is jpg. JPG is saving perfectly and pdf is cropped.

Comment: So why you need to pass from the drawing cache of the ImageView to get the Bitmap to save in the PDF? Try what Tarun suggested, if that won't work i will copy here the code i use to convert images to PDF with Itext

Comment: @MatPag it worked but still there is border which makes the pdf quite useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code

```
Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
myImg.scaleToFit(PageSize.A4);
float scaler = ((document.getPageSize().getWidth() - document.leftMargin()
                - document.rightMargin() - 0) / image.getWidth()) * 100;

myImg.scalePercent(scaler);
document.add(myImg);
```

Comment: image is missing shall i take width of myImg?

Comment: Hey thanks it works! I was wondering if we could remove the borders around it white and black borders